# Is there a bug in the modifier stack 2.93?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to use the apply as shape key, or save as shape key on a cloth sim on the modifier stack. However nothing happens, no shape key is created in either case and the modifier remains when using apply. No error is generated either.

I've also noticed that if there's a subsurf in the the stack and I try to apply a modifier that's before it the subsurf get's applied instead.

Can anyone help?
Al

Comment: can u please provide your blend file?

Comment: It's not a problem with the blend file. It happens even if I start from new. could it be something in the preferences?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it may be a bug in this version. I've just installed 2.93.6 and the issue has been resolved.